# Representing inner classes in typescript type definitions

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I wanted to create type definitions of a library that exists just in form of javascript.

Being quite new I read the documentation [on the official manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) along with all examples.

There is a case, though, that I don't really understand:

The library offers the programmer a global variable, `foo` that contains both classes and references to instances, so that one could, for example, trigger a search by using (in javascript)

```
var filter = new foo.Filter();
var results = foo.search.performSearch(filter);
```

the same `foo`, however, is also available in the `window` object so using `window.foo.[...]` helds the same results.

How can I represent this fact?
I initially started by defining the following (by basically copying what's in the library's API reference):

```
interface FooObject {
    foo: Foo;
}

interface Window extends FooObject { }

interface Foo {
    search: Search;
}

interface Search {
    performSearch(): void;
}

declare const foo: Foo;
```

This way the syntax `foo.search.performSearch()` is accepted and so is `window.foo.search.performSearch()`.

The only ways (that I read about) to be able to represent the first part, `new foo.Filter()`, would be to

```
declare namespace /*or module*/ foo {
    class Filter {
        // [...]
    }
}
```

But namespaces [are also declared as values](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), so this overrides the first `foo` definition and the compiler complains. Plus, even if it worked, I don't think that `new window.foo.filter()` would behave as expected and would surely throw a compiler error.

Of course I could just do the following

```
declare namespace /*(or module)*/ foo {
    const search: Search;

    interface Search {}

    class Filter {}
}
```

without declaring the `const foo: Foo` or the class `Foo` but I have no way in a d.ts file to assign the module to `window.foo`, the compiler complains.
Plus this is not a solution that allows me to stick to the API Doc of the library that explicitly tells what I explained above about the hierarchy of Window, having the Foo class etc.

How can I represent this structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You represent a class by its constructor.

```
interface FooObject {
    foo: Foo;
}

interface Window extends FooObject { }

interface Foo {
    search: Search;
    Filter: new () => Filter;
}

interface Filter {
}

interface Search {
    performSearch(filter: Filter): void;
}

declare const foo: Foo;
```

Comment: Brilliant, that didn't occur to me! Just to add: in case the constructor had parameters, I believe that the following would be ok: `Filter: new (param: type) => Filter;` and I there should be no need to declare the constructor in the Filter interface/class as well, right? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Oh, almost forgetting: what about constructor overloading?

Comment: Try this syntax for the overload: `Filter: { new(): Filter, new(par1?: number): Filter };`